# IBM ODM rule designer comparing 2 collections items

Tags: java, loops, collections, odm, jrules

So I want to design a rule that checks if the items in collection A are all in collection B. However, rule designer only lets me compare a SINGLE item form collection A with ALL items in collection B.

I would appriciate advice with how to go about achieving this. I thought maybe it might be possible to design a Java file that handles it and pass the collections over. But I am also having trouble design this feature as well.

So far I am stumped.